# How determine the scale of a decimal type column with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, decimal, scale

I need to change a decimal type column with precision 16 and scale 2 to precision 16 and scale 5, for which I would do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.my_table ALTER COLUMN my_column DECIMAL(16, 5)
```

But to avoid making this change every time the application runs, I would like to read the column scale and if it is different from 5, the line above would be executed.

Is there a way to get the scale of a column of decimal type?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: You would need to do this using dynamic SQL -- by constructing the alter statement as a string and executing that.  That said, something is wrong with your application if you feel the need to do this more than once.  The data structure should not need to change like this.

Comment: ‍You can find all the columns which are 16,2 and change those to 16,5 at once. Then you may not need to check every time you run queries.

Comment: I'm working with SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the scale of a column of decimal type?

You can query `information_schema.columns`:

```
select column_name, numeric_precision, numeric_scale 
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'dbo' and table_name = 'my_table' and column_name = 'my_column'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information from the `sys` objects:

```
SELECT ct.name AS DataType,
       c.precision,
       c.scale
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
     JOIN sys.types ct ON c.system_type_id = ct.system_type_id
WHERE s.name = N'Your Schema'
  AND t.name = N'Your Table'
  AND c.name = N'Your Column';
```